# How can use tab space in variable

Tags: php

"\t" is not working on my code

Tried to put a lot on .'     '.

```
$name = '<h4 class="h4">NAME: '."\t".$firstname .' '. $midname .' '. $lastname. '</h4>';
```

Expected out put is 
NAME:             Mark stack

Comment: You want to display 5 spaces in HTML? `Expected out put is NAME: Mark stack` is not clear that looks correct.

Comment: You do realize that a browser doesn't do anything with tabs? It's shown as a space, and multiple spaces are shown as if they were one space. A tab isn't a HTML character and a browser is not a word-processor. See also: [How to create extra space in HTML or a web page](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001662.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the Name: inside the `<span>Name:</span>` and set margin-right to the span to get your desired space.

```
echo $name = '<h4 class="h4"><span style = "margin-right: 20px;">NAME:</span> '.$firstname .' '. $midname .' '. $lastname. '</h4>';
```

[Demo](https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/bjs)

Answer (score 0):

html syntax cant read tab.... it dosent know it , as a charachter.
use this. `<pre></pre>`